# Скопировать выборочные файлы по шаблону * в директориях с сохранением структуры и без лишнего

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно из некой директории с примерной структурой

```
dir
 a-sub1
  a-sub2
   preview.png
  b-sub2
   preview.png
 b-sub1
  c-sub2
   preview.png
```

По мимо этих субдиректорий и файла `preview.png` есть и другие файлы, включая в этих субдирикториях, и другие субдириктории.
Скопировать нужно только эту структуру, т.е. файлы `preview.png` и их 2 уровня субдирекотрий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/dir/parent && cp --parents dir/*/*/preview.png /path/to/target/dir
```

Comment: `cd && /path/to/dir/parent &&` - думаю тут указано лишнее логическое и `&&` после `cd`

Comment: @ipatev_nn Благодарю, очепатался. :-)